# I am getting error while i am runing my code into the Flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Exception has occurred.
"Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:58511/dart_sdk.js:5063:11)
at platform_channel.MethodChannel.new._invokeMethod (http://localhost:58511/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1555:21)
at _invokeMethod.next ()
at http://localhost:58511/dart_sdk.js:40192:33
at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:58511/dart_sdk.js:40062:59)
at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:58511/dart_sdk.js:34983:29)
at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:58511/dart_sdk.js:35551:49)
at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:58511/dart_sdk.js:35589:17)
at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:58511/dart_sdk.js:35437:23)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:58511/dart_sdk.js:35458:35)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:58511/dart_sdk.js:40330:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:58511/dart_sdk.js:40336:13)
at http://localhost:58511/dart_sdk.js:35811:9"

Comment: Are you importing `dart:io` in your code?

Comment: I am getting this error too, have you found a solution for it?

Comment: Hello i haven't found the solution yet , but in found the issue this issue is happning due to flutter web because flutter web don't have document directory , which is avilable in iOS & andoird .. but now i am facing issue of document directory in flutter web

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Provider then put listen false,
i was facing same issue when i have used listen true[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).